# How to create a child block programmatically?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have a page that has some template block included programmatically as follows:

```
public function indexAction() {
    $this->loadLayout();
    $block = $this->getLayout()
        ->createBlock('core/template')
        ->setTemplate('somefolder/sometemplate.phtml');
    
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
    $this->renderLayout();

}
```

I would like to put inside the **sometemplate.phtml**, **$this->getChildHtml('somechild')** to insert another block.

I tried

```
$box = $this->getLayout()
->createBlock('page/html')
->setTemplate('somefolder/somechild.phtml');
$block->append($box);
```

But it didn't work. How can I do it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I solved the problem by using **setChild** method as follows:

```
$block->setChild('somealias',$childBlock);
```

And so I can use

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('somealias'); ?>
```

Comment: if i already add alias from $childBlock. what to do with first parameter of setChild?

Comment: specify a different alias?

Comment: hi @RicardoMartins, in this example, somealias is also the phtml filename you have taken ?

Comment: hi @SagarPPanchal. No. The template phtml is specified on the xml or in the block class (php).

Answer (score 0):

To add up to Ricardo Martins's answer
If you need it in a block directly you can do what product price does

`Mage_Catalog_Block_Product`:

```
public function getPriceHtml($product)
{
    $this->setTemplate('catalog/product/price.phtml');
    $this->setProduct($product);
    return $this->toHtml();
}
```